# Puphpeteer - Get text and href-attribute from link

Tags: php

I am using `"@nesk/puphpeteer": "^2.0.0"` [Link to Github-Repo](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer) and want get the text and the `href`-attribute from a link.

I tried the following:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;

$debug = true;

$puppeteer = new Puppeteer([
    'read_timeout' => 100,
    'debug' => $debug,
]);
$browser = $puppeteer->launch([
    'headless' => !$debug,
    'ignoreHTTPSErrors' => true,
]);

$page = $browser->newPage();
$page->goto('http://example.python-scraping.com/');

//get text and link
$links = $page->querySelectorXPath('//*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a', JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])
    ->body('return node.textContent;'));

// iterate over links and print each link and its text

// get single text
$singleText = $page->querySelectorXPath('//*[@id="pagination"]/a', JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])
    ->body('return node.textContent;'));


$browser->close();
```

When I run the above script I get the nodes from the page, BUT I cannot access the attributes or the text?

Any suggestions how to do this?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: In Node Js you use const hrefs1 = await page.evaluate(
      () => Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'),
        a => a.getAttribute('href')
      )
    ); what will be the equivalent in  nesk/puphpeteer?

Comment: Can you please describe which HTML attrs, values, ... you're interested in. I would prepare the example source for that specific request.

Answer (score 6):

`querySelectorXPath` return array of `ElementHandle`. one more thing `querySelectorXPath` does not support callback function.

first get all node `ElementHandle`

```
$links = $page->querySelectorXPath('//*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a');
```

then loop over links to access attributes or text of node

```
foreach($links as $link){
   // for text
    $text = $link->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])
    ->body('return node.innerText;'));

  // for link
  $link = $link->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])
    ->body('return node.href;'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is just an intermediate answer - I would update once I've got more specific requests on HTML attrs or other expectations to be retrieved.

**tl;dr**: Mentioned composer package `nesk/puphpeteer` really is just a wrapper to underlying NodeJS based implementation of `puppeteer`. Thus, accessing data and structures has to be "similar" to their JavaScript counterparts...

Maybe [`Codeception`](https://codeception.com/) (headless) or [`symfony/dom-crawler`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) (raw markup) might be better and more mature alternatives.

---

Anyway, let's pick the example from above and go through it step by step:

```php
$links = $page->querySelectorXPath(
  '//*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a', 
  JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])->body('return node.textContent;')
);
```

- XPath query [`$x()` would result in an array of `ElementHandle` items](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.2.0&show=api-elementhandlexexpression)
- to access exported `node.textContent` (from `JsFunction`), corresponding data gets [fetched via `ElementHandle.getProperty(prop)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.2.0&show=api-elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname)
- exporting a scalar value (to PHP) is then done [via `ElementHandle.jsonValue()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.2.0&show=api-elementhandlejsonvalue)

Thus, after that we would have something like this:

```php
$links = $page->querySelectorXPath(
  '//*[@id="results"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a', 
  JsFunction::createWithParameters(['node'])->body('return node.textContent;')
);

/** @var \Nesk\Puphpeteer\Resources\ElementHandle $link */
foreach ($links as $link) {
  var_dump($link->getProperty('textContent')->jsonValue());
}
```

Which outputs the following raw data (as retrieved from http://example.python-scraping.com/):

```
string(12) " Afghanistan"
string(14) " Aland Islands"
string(8) " Albania"
string(8) " Algeria"
string(15) " American Samoa"
string(8) " Andorra"
string(7) " Angola"
string(9) " Anguilla"
string(11) " Antarctica"
string(20) " Antigua and Barbuda"
```